# Shooting in 4k and battery life question

Tags: battery

I have a Canon SX530 HS Camera I bought last year on black Friday. We took it to Disney and I was shooting in 4k for pics most of the time. but when I shot video on it, it ate the battery up bad. Will shooting pictures in 4k kill the battery as badly? or did the battery just crap out because of the video? I might add this camera is NOT a DSLR camera.

Comment: There is no such thing as 4K pictures, do you perhaps mean full resolution? This question seems unclear

Comment: Are you asking if shooting high resolution photos impacts battery life vs low resolution photos? Or are you asking if shooting photos impacts battery life vs shooting video?

Comment: There are some cameras that have a "4K photo" mode -
 this is essentially just recording a 4K video, then extracting frames from it. Though that Canon doesn't do that anyway. It only goes up to 1920x1080 for video.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the camera, but generally yes, shooting video will drain the battery faster.  The camera has to encode the video being recorded and store it to the memory card, which is a much more intensive operation than capturing photos when you hit the shutter release.  If your camera doesn't use an electronic viewfinder or a screen, then it also has to leave the sensor turned on all the time while video is recording, but not in between photos.  ( If you do have an evf or screen on,  then the sensor will always be on either way.)

Even on my high end Canon 5D Mark iii, I can shoot photos for days without changing the battery, but shooting a couple hours of video will blow through it.